# Raspberry pi not powering

Tags: pi-2

I have a raspberry that I want to power with a battery (12V 7A) through a tension reducer (5V, max 3A). When I attach the board to the charger nothing happens. When I attach the same charger to a smartphone it charges the phone. At the same time if I power the raspberry with the telephone charger, it works well. I already tested both the charger and they have the same specifications.
My board decided that to don't like the charger I've chosen.

Comment: What's a tension reducer and more specifically what's yours exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure that the right name is "tension reducer".... In italian is "riduttore di tensione". Anyway, I bought this one: [link](http://amzn.eu/c9wEowK)

Comment: @LorenzoFioroni Well, you seem to have found yet another power supply which doesn't work with the RPi. Send it back if you still have buyer's protection. Buy a different one (if you don't want to gamble, get the official one).